# Dropdown does not fill from BLL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to fill a dropdown in the pageload by using a BLL and DAL class.
This is the code

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles Me.Load
        dropBrand.DataSource = BLLManufacturer.selectManufacturers()
        dropBrand.DataTextField = "ManufacturerName"
        dropBrand.DataValueField = "ManufacturerID"
        dropBrand.DataBind()

        dropModel.DataSource = BLLModel.selectModelsByBrand(Convert.ToInt16(dropBrand.SelectedValue))
        dropModel.DataTextField = "ModelName"
        dropModel.DataValueField = "ModelID"
        dropModel.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

The first dropdown fills up with brands as it is supposed to do, but the second does not.
The second dropdown needs to show car models by the chosen brand in the first dropdown. However the dropBrand.SelectedValue always returns 0 whatever brand I select. Without the convert toint16 it doesnt work either nor with convert toint32 or toint64. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What you have won't work as it's only doing the initial data bind to the drop down lists.

You need to set up a `SelectedIndexChanged` event that will fire for the `BLLManufacturer` drop down list then get the selected value from that list and bind the data to the `BLLModel` list. Something roughly like this (code not tested) -

```
Private Sub BLLManufacturer_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BLLManufacturer.SelectedIndexChanged
       ' Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
        Dim curItem As String = BLLManufacturer.SelectedItem.ToString()

        dropModel.DataSource = BLLModel.selectModelsByBrand(Convert.ToInt16(curItem ))
        dropModel.DataTextField = "ModelName"
        dropModel.DataValueField = "ModelID"
        dropModel.DataBind()
End Sub
```

You could also do what you want via AJAX and avoid the page posting back.